# How to set up a IPv6 to IPv4 gateway for VPS

Tags: ipv6, vps, ipv4

**Condition**

- IPv6 and IPv4 enabled VPS
- IPv6 and IPv4 enabled Client(Could be PC or Mac)

**Problem**

Client get restricted IPv4 connection whereas IPv6 connection is unlimited.

**Solution**

Client connects to VPS using IPv6, then browse the Internet(IPv4) using this connection.

I don't know if it makes any sense, if so, hope someone could provide me with a solution setting things up.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Set up a proxy server like Squid on the VPS and connect to it from the client via IPv6.

For instance, if you set up Squid on its default port of 3128 and your VPS's IPv6 address is `2001:db8:22:7::88`, then you would configure your browser to use an HTTP proxy of `2001:db8:22:7::88` and port 3128.

Comment: thx! I will give a shot!